# Tkinter listbox calculate

Tags: tkinter

How to use tkinter listbox to the calculation...
The user can make a choice in two listbox ,Function should be taken from the upper listbox dic key And lower listbox dic value....
I have a code like this:(But it does n't work)

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def calculate():
    a = int(l1.curselection())
    b = int(si1.curselection())
    t = a+b
    t=Label(aken,text="answer: %.2f" % tulemus).grid(row=7,column=5)
    return(t)




aken = Tk()
aken.title('kalk')
aken.configure(background='#E6F3FE')
aken.geometry("420x200")




l1 = ttk.Label(aken, text="2 ", background="#E6F3FE")
l1.grid(column=0, row=3, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=(N, W, ))

l1 = Listbox(aken, height=1)
pr = {50:60,80:46}
for i in pr:
    l1.insert(END, i)
    l1.grid(column=1, row=3, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=(N, W, E))

si1 = ttk.Label(aken, text="1 ", background="#E6F3FE")
si1.grid(column=0, row=4, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=(N, W, ))

si1 = Listbox(aken, height=1)
pr = {50:60,80:46,8:6}
for i in pr:
    si1.insert(END, i)
    si1.grid(column=1, row=4, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=(N, W, E))



nupp = ttk.Button(aken, text="Calculate", command=calculate)
nupp.grid(column=1, row=7, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=(N, S, W, E))


aken.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main problem here - your `calculate` function. You got error here because `curselection()` returns a tuple. Of course, you can use `curselection()[0]`, but there're can be no selection and each time you need to convert a string to an integer.

So we can workaround it with `get('active')` and since your dict full of integers - we're free from conversion:

```
def calculate():
    a = l1.get('active')
    b = si1.get('active')
    tulemus = a+b
    Label(aken, text="answer: %.2f" % tulemus).grid(row=7, column=5)
```

Another weak spot - `grid` inside a loop. Feel free to move `grid` around!
So now your code "works" or "produce no error":

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


def calculate():
    a = l1.get('active')
    b = si1.get('active')
    tulemus = a+b
    Label(aken, text="answer: %.2f" % tulemus).grid(row=7, column=5)

aken = Tk()
aken.title('kalk')
aken.configure(background='#E6F3FE')
aken.geometry("420x200")

l1 = ttk.Label(aken, text="2 ", background="#E6F3FE")
l1.grid(column=0, row=3, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=(N, W, ))

l1 = Listbox(aken, height=1)
l1.grid(column=1, row=3, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=(N, W, E))

pr = {50: 60, 80: 46}
for i in pr:
    l1.insert(END, i)

si1 = ttk.Label(aken, text="1 ", background="#E6F3FE")
si1.grid(column=0, row=4, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=(N, W, ))

si1 = Listbox(aken, height=1)
si1.grid(column=1, row=4, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=(N, W, E))

pr = {50: 60, 80: 46, 8: 6}
for i in pr:
    si1.insert(END, i)

nupp = ttk.Button(aken, text="Calculate", command=calculate)
nupp.grid(column=1, row=7, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=(N, S, W, E))

aken.mainloop()
```

Also in each loop you iterate over dict keys, hence you listboxes are both populated with keys. Your idea isn't clear to me, but if you need values in lower listbox - use this loop ([iterating over `dict`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops)):

```
for i in pr.values():
    si1.insert(END, i)
```

Also:

- [Why is “import *” bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386714/why-is-import-bad)
- [Best way to structure a tkinter application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466561/best-way-to-structure-a-tkinter-application)

Comment: I have one more problem ,If I want the user to see key ,but ,function  use value... How  i to do it?

Comment: @JanekLass, it's up to you. And it's better to create new question with your ideas and desired behaviour. But idea is simple - track  selection changes of desired listbox.